# object fail when called from for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing a weird error that I don't know how to handle

so an object is created from a method

```
procesed_sequences = sequence.find(seq_in_list)
```

This procesed_sequences return an object:

In normal condition, when we call for loop on this procesed_sequences:

```
for seq in procesed_sequences:
    record.append(seq)
```

It is giving an error at a specific seq

```
File "sequence.py", line 290, in run for seq in procesed_sequences:
File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sequence_finder.py", line 34, in look_sequence
    seq_start = row.index("1")  # start of sequence
ValueError: '1' is not in list
```

if I try to print the seq object

```
for seq in procesed_sequences:
    print(seq)
```

It will print all the seq object until the problematic one and fail

so I thought using try and except

```
try:
   record.append(seq)
except:
   print(f"This sequence is giving error in")
   print(e)
```

However, the try and except doesn't work, it seems the error happened at the try part when seq object is generated, now there is no way for me to go access the sequence script atm, how do I just ask seq object to not get call in the procesed_sequences if it's giving error

Thank you

Comment: What is the error? A traceback might help

Comment: I add the error on the top, but at the moment there is no way for me to access the sequence_finder.py since I don't have permission, and I am wondering why try and except doesn't work when calling object

Comment: “procesed_sequences” is a generator, the error is being raised during the iteration over that generator. You would need to wrap the for loop in the try/except to catch the error

Comment: I tried that, but that means I can't get all other seq object from the procesed_sequences?

Comment: Yes, the generator has raised an exception, it will not produce anymore values

Comment: anyway to avoid that? like still get other sequences but ignore the bad one?

Comment: If you can edit the generator then you could catch the exception and continue after handling it somehow. Once a generator has exited by raising an exception there is no way to continue it

Comment: `sequence_finder.py` is in "site-packages", is it a package that you have downloaded? If so which package is it?

Comment: it's a package that I installed through our company, I don't have permission to go edit the error for now, and even though I can edit the install package, but then that will break the rule since I shouldn't be editing script that is install so I am trying to not breaking the rule for now

Comment: The package is supplied by another team in your company? I suggest raising a bug/issue with the team that maintains that package

Answer (score 1):

Norman can you please put a try and except block inside the find function mentioned below from the sequence.py file.

```
procesed_sequences = sequence.find(seq_in_list)
```

It's not failing in the try-except block in the above is because it's been running on append operation. If possible please share the code for find function from the squence.py file. Problem seems to lie there

Comment: Thanks for the response, yea unfortunately I don't have access to that script at the moment due to permission error, that's why I am trying to fix at the wrapper script level

Comment: The problem is that your generator is doing a lazy evaluation and creating a seq object at the time of appending to the list and that's why it's failing at that time. Do you have any inbuilt logger inside the restricted file? It would be really difficult to try debugging the error from the wrapper class

Comment: yea at the moment I am not trying to debug, just trying to skip that seq object with problem and want to know if there is any other way to do so

Comment: One thing you can do is that create a counter variable and print the index of processed_sequence list at which it is failing and hardcode inside the code to skip that. Try it and let me know if that works

Comment: I think that will work, but I can't just do that for this one sample, I think best option for me right now is to skip this sample and let the upper management decide what they can do before I get permission to tackle the bug

Comment: yup exactly, do that and best of lick :)

Comment: Do upvote me if you find my insights useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232433/discussion-between-alok-raj-and-norman-kuo).